# How to synchronize Local database with a remote database using Django?

Tags: django, database-design, mysql-python, django-database

I just want concurrency in the local and remote database.
The changes made to local database should be reflected to a remote database automatically.
In short explain me how to concurrently update multiple database servers.

Comment: Why do you want to achieve this from Django?. I think it could be better from a pure database point of view depending on the your DBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to solve this on a DB level, you may want to have a look at Django's built in support for [multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/).